# How to change a birthday to a certain date in matching lines

Tags: linux, sed

Using `sed`, how would I change `Popeye`’s birthday to `11/14/46`?  Assume you don’t know Popeye’s original birthday.

The input filename is `datebook`, as follows:

```
Arthur Putie:923-835-8745:23 Wimp Lane, Kensington, DL 38758:8/31/69:126000
Popeye Sailor:156-454-3322:945 Bluto Street, Anywhere, USA 29358:3/19/35:22350
Jose Santiago:385-898-8357:38 Fife Way, Abilene, TX 39673:1/5/58:95600
```

I tried

```
sed ‘^\(/Popeye/s/[0-9]{5}\):/\1:11/14/46’ datebook
```

but it did not work.

Comment: What is your question?  You want to write a parser to pick out the relevant data and replace it for you?  That might be better on Stack Overflow, but as it is I'm not even sure this is a real question.

Comment: Reopened since after the OP's clarification, this question became answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numbers, slash, numbers, slash, numbers. Use an alternate separator to avoid backslashed slashes:

```
sed '/Popeye/s,[0-9]\+/[0-9]\+/[0-9]\+,11/14/46,'
```

Comment: sed '/Popeye/s,[0-9]\+/[0-9]\+/[0-9]\+,11/14/46,' => This works great. Thank you Choroba